# Confusion with combining Math.max and Math.min

Tags: javascript

There is a formula I have read on stackoverflow and one thing is not clear to me, more on that below. maxMax returns the second value within the brackets and the mathMin the first one.

So let us assume I am making a calculation where let us say:

max = 2 * 10
min = 2 * 5

In order to calculate the max and min in one line I would have to use this formula:

```
Math.max(a, Math.min(x, b))
```

The issue I am having is that math.max looks as if it returns math.min in this formula. Does that not destroy the cause of max or am I missunderstanding something?

For example in an application that strictly needs to define a min and max value for something the above formula is correct or not?
.

Comment: _The issue I am having is that max.max returns math.min._ What does this mean? What is `max.max`?

Comment: @Asperger this is a two statement, max = 2 * 10; 
 min = 2 * 5

Comment: @hindmost corrected my question. Thank you for hinting to my bad formulation

Comment: "For example in an application that strictly needs to define a min and max value for something the above formula is correct or not? ." --- what does it mean? The expression would return a single number.

Comment: What values do you have in `var a`, `var x` and `var b`?

Comment: @zerkms indeed but let us assume I a number randomizer or a voting system and wanted to tell javascript to accept a minimum of that and a maximum of this. How would I do that`? What formula is there?

Comment: Can you please clarify: 1) what you expect and 2) what you get exactly

Comment: @Asperger it's still not clear. "a minimum of that and a maximum of this" --- o_O

Comment: @zerkms how do I create a compressor of some sort? Let us say I do a calculation and I get different values every time but want to limit those values by assigning a minimum and maximum...a limiter. I cant elaborate any more than this... sorry : (

Comment: @Asperger Sorry, but your definition and question are quite unclear. According the last comment here, I think that you are looking for something like `if(value < max && value > min) { //do something }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Math.max(a, Math.min(x, b));
```

Assuming `a`, `b`, and `x` are numbers, `Math.min(x,b)` is always resolved and number is returned.

Taking the result to `Math.max` method, action is performed and larger number is returned.

It could also be defined in 2 steps as

```
var min = Math.min(x, b);
Math.max(a, min);
```

Reading the above example should be more clear and easier to understand.

See more examples at [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

Comment: Math.max(a, min); if "a" is higher than min then will it take "a"? The order does not matter does it?

Answer (score 1):

The naming of the functions `Math.min` and `Math.max` is a bit ambiguous.

In order to clip a value to a given range you can use them like this:

```
clippedValue = Math.max(lowerBound, Math.min(value, upperBound))
```

`Math.max` takes an arbitrary amount of numbers and returns the biggest one while `Math.min` also takes an arbitrary amount of numbers and returns the smallest.

This behavior might be in contradiction to your expectations when you're looking for a way to clip values. `Math.min` doesn't clip a value to a minimum bound, just as `Math.max` doesn't clip a value to a maximum bound.

But (accidentally?) they work as desired if you change their names. So `Math.max` with two arguments works like a hypothetical `Math.clipMin`, just as `Math.min` with two argments works like a hypothetical `Math.clipMax`.